# Invalid Columns in referenced table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Im setting up a couple tables in a new database. I have a `Users` table, a `Companies` table, a `UserCompanies` table (so a user can work for many different companies), and a `UserPay` Table.

```
CREATE TABLE tblUsers
(
[UserTableID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    
[UserEmail] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[UserFirstName] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
[UserLastName] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
[UserAddress1] VARCHAR(45) NULL,
[UserAddress2] VARCHAR(45) SPARSE NULL,
[UserCity] VARCHAR(45) NULL,
[UserState] VARCHAR(2) NULL,
[UserZipCode] VARCHAR(10) NULL,
[UserPhone] VARCHAR(13) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE tblCompanies
(
[CompanyID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[CompanyName] VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
[CompanyAddress1] VARCHAR(45) NULL,
[CompanyAddress2] VARCHAR(45) SPARSE NULL,
[CompanyCity] VARCHAR(45) NULL,
[CompanyState] VARCHAR(2) NULL,
[CompanyPhone] VARCHAR(13) NULL,
[CompanyPhoneExtension] VARCHAR(8) NULL,
[CompanyContactFirstName] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
[CompanyContactLastName] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE tblUserCompanies
(
[UserTableID] INT NOT NULL,
[CompanyID] INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (UserTableID, CompanyID),
FOREIGN KEY (UserTableID) REFERENCES tblUsers(UserTableID),
FOREIGN KEY (CompanyID) REFERENCES tblCompanies(CompanyID)  
)

CREATE TABLE tblUserPay
(
[UserPayID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[UserID] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES tblUserCompanies(UserTableID),
[UserCompany] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES tblUserCompanies(CompanyID),
[NetPay] MONEY NOT NULL,
[PayDate] DATE NOT NULL
)
```

The problem is I get an error which states.. "There are no primary or candidate keys in referenced table `tblUserCompanies` that match the referencing column list in `tblUserPay`.

I dont understand why Im getting error. Same data type, foreign keys in tact, primary keys established. Only thing I can think of is that its throwing an error because i have a foreign key linking to another foreign key. Please help if you can! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking to a composite key, you need to have one foreign key reference that includes both columns, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE tblUserPay
(
[DriverPayID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[UserID] INT NOT NULL,
[UserCompany] INT NOT NULL,
[NetPay] MONEY NOT NULL,
[PayDate] DATE NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (UserID, UserCompany) REFERENCES tblUserCompanies(UserTableID, CompanyID)
)
```

Comment: DOH! I knew that! Thank you, fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this sample

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1(
    Table1Col1 int NOT NULL
    ,Table1Col2 int NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
        Table1Col1
        ,Table1Col2)    
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2(
    Table2Col1 int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ,Table1Col1 int NOT NULL
    ,Table1Col2 int NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1 FOREIGN KEY(
        Table1Col1
        ,Table1Col2)
        REFERENCES dbo.Table1(
        Table1Col1
        ,Table1Col2
    )
);
```